# How can I verify that variance(factor)=1 from Exploratory factor analysis results?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

I am reading upon Exploratory factor analysis. One of the assumptions of the Orthogonal factor model is that $$ \sigma^2(factor)=1 $$. Reference via "Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis-by Johnson and Wichern".

[image]
I am a bit confused about this. Which variance is this?
a) Sum of squares of loadings of this factor against the indicators? This can't be 1 because this is what we use to decide how much variance is explained by each factor. (I don't have an intuition for what the last 6-7 words in previous sentence mean)
b) Variance of factor scores using standardized or mean-centered data?  (I checked this isn't 1 either)
c) Variance of factor scores using standardized factor loadings and standardized input variables? (this comes out to be 1).

Please help me get some intuition for this.

Comment: The formula is indeed weird. Can you add links/citation? A factor's variance is known to be its sum of squared loadings.

Comment: @ttnphns It is there on page page 482 of book Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis-by Johnson and Wichern.

Comment: Thanks for adding the source. I see. It's correct. In the orthogonal _factor model_ (see formulae 9-1, 9-2) factor values F are implied _in standardized_ (mean 0, sd 1) form. They have to. Only under this condition (plus orthogonality) _loadings_ - which are covariances b/w factors and variables - can serve _also the_ regression coefficients of the model. (Recall it: if predictors in multiple regression are orthogonal and _taken_ standardized, coefficients = covariances.) However, real factor variances are not 1, they are sums of their squared loadings.

Comment: @ttnphns: So if that is the case then the factor loadings should sum up to 1 after doing say "varimax" rotation. The loadings I get from Principal Factor method are definitely not going to have sum of squared loadings=1 as you pointed out(thanks for that). But I am curious if we do orthogonal rotation, why don't we get factor loadings directly such that the variance = 1?

Comment: No... Varimax - because it keeps factors orthogonal - changes nothing in FA "laws". Varimax simply rotates the loading matrix for factors to become more interpretable. Of course, varimax changes factors' variances (loadings SS) - because factors become different conceptually, substantively (not mathematically).

Comment: To reiterate my second comment. factors have different variances, of course. But in the factor model expression, they are presumed standardized. It is under this condition that loadings are covariances between (these standardized) factors and the variables, _and_ the loadings can restore covariance matrix of the variables by `loadings*t(loadings)+diag(uniquenesses)`.

Comment: @ttnphns That last point made it slightly more clear for me. Thanks. So when you say "Standardized factors", how do you do that? By standardizing the loadings? or by taking factor scores (without standardizing loadings) and then standardizing the factor scores? Are the two cases equivalent?

Comment: Just compute factor scores and standardize them. You should know, however, that estimated (computed) _factor scores_ are not the exact _factor values_ implied in factor model, only their reasonable approximations. True factor values remain unknown. This what distinquishes FA from PCA.